# PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader - automatically Linked dbf file

Tags: postgis, postgresql, dbf, pgadmin-3

This is my system:

```
Windows 7

Postgresql 9.5

PGADMIN 3

PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader plugin
```

I have imported data from a DBF file correctly with the plugin.

My problem: This DBF file changes every day. Is there any option to have the file linked with my Postgresql database?

Comment: The best option would be to update the database table directly rather than the DBF file.

Comment: I have no control. I cant update directly the database. Thanks

Comment: So even if there is some way to link a Postgresql table to an external dbf. you won't be able to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You might consiider PostGIS FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) - it will connect to remote files such as Shapefiles or CSV, and they will appear and be queryable just like 'normal' PostGres tables.

I think you'd need to use the GDAL/OGR FDW library - it supports shapefile connections.

But don't take my word for it:
http://postgis.net/2014/12/19/postgis_fdw/